# fatal error U1077: 'cl' : return code '0x1' new

Tags: windows, qt

I installed Qt 5.2.1 64-bit for Desktop (MSVC 2012).

Whenever I run the application i get the following error, please keep in mind that:

- I have VS Ultimate 2012
- I tried some answers already but still get the same problem
- I have CDB installed

If I use nmake:

```
15:40:30: Running steps for project hi...
15:40:30: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
15:40:30: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\nmake.exe" 
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\nmake.exe -f Makefile.Debug
cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc /Fddebug\hi.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64\include" -I"..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2012" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\FUJITSU\AppData\Local\Temp\nm2248.tmp
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cl' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\nmake.exe' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
15:40:30: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\nmake.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project hi (kit: Desktop Qt 5.2.1 MSVC2012 64bit)
When executing step 'Make'
```

If I use jom :

```
15:46:19: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc /Fddebug\hi.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64\include" -I"..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2012" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\FUJITSU\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.6696.0.jom
jom: C:\Users\FUJITSU\build-hi-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\main.obj] Error 2
jom: C:\Users\FUJITSU\build-hi-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
15:46:19: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project hi (kit: Desktop Qt 5.2.1 MSVC2012 64bit)
When executing step 'Make'
```

Why am I getting the errors and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running this without environment set up. Launch `cmd.exe` using `Visual Studio Developer Prompt` item from the Start menu and then use `jom`/`nmake` tools from there.